# Как выгодно обработать видео?

Tags: видео

Добрый вечер! Недавно передо мной встала задача - обработать рекламный видеоролик, добавить переходы и всякие эффекты. Только вот уже неделю в поисках решения этой проблемы. Проблема заключается в том, что видеозапись была снята на обычную видеокамеру. Причём, несколько дублей были заключены в одну видеозапись. Но мне не понятно, как разделить это видео на части. К тому же, пожалуйста, подскажите программу для обработки видео. Перепробовал уже около десятка. Убедительная просьба: Sony Vegas Pro не предлагать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Premiere (cs6, cs5)

- создаем проект под нужное разрешение
- импортируем видео
- перетягиваем на видео-дорожки
- включаем инструмент резки Cut (клавиша "С")
- кликаем на дорожках ролик в тех местах где нужно отделить сцены
- получившиеся куски располагаем по дорожкам друг над другом
- в области перекрытия кусков можно перетягивать эффекты (панель эффектов и переходов надо предварительно открыть)

Конечно очень грубо описано, но примерно так.
За помощью и ответами в скайп - swa512.

Answer (score 0):

Поищите в интернете Cyberlink Powerdirector 11 Ultra. Мощный видеоредактор с кучей эффектов и переходов, который выделяется дружелюбным и не перегруженным интерфейсом. Есть русская версия, поэтому не думаю, что нужны какие-то инструкции. Но если вдруг не разберётесь - пишите